# What is Demo Content wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

have installed a theme that need a Demo Content, but what is it? 
I know that it is a xml file and When I import it the theme change totally

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's demo content to test the themes functionality after purchase.

Answer (score 0):

When we purchase theme.  Theme provider provide us builted pages layout of all controls they provided. We can use this pages for reference and for built our page layout.

It is .xml file. We can import it in our site from 
Dashboard > tools > Install importer then run importer > select file > assign admin > import.